# How to select multiple rows using ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select multiple rows that ordered by desc. as a example, I want to select the lastly added rows for Kandy, Ampara & Anuradhapura.. Please view screen shot of my database from the link below.

[image: a]

I tried:

```
SELECT thripstot, g_midgetot, l_foldertot 
FROM pest_data 
WHERE district = 'ampara' OR district = 'kandy' OR district = 'anuradhapura' 
order by id desc 
limit 0,1;
```

and that's not provides the result that I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I did understand you correctly, you want to get the latest record for each specified `district` defined in the `where` clause.

You can use subquery which separately gets the latest record for each `district` via the maximum `ID` if it was set as *Auto_increment* column. In order to get all the rows from the selected latest row, you need to join it with the original table provided that it matches on the `district` and the `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.thripstot, a.g_midgetot, a.l_foldertot 
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  district, MAX(id) max_id
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY district
        ) b ON  a.district = b.district AND
                a.id = b.max_id
WHERE   a.district IN ('ampara','kandy', 'anuradhapura')
```

Comment: how if he want one (last row) for each ('ampara','kandy', 'anuradhapura')

Comment: @Akam the query will give you the latest row for each district based on `ID`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. that's the perfect one for me. But in your query there should be a.district. It missed alias

Comment: @Chaturanga yes, you are right, so it will not throw ambiguous column error.